# Rss feeds view showing encoded special character in title

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I created an view to display rss feeds on a site for title it shows special characters in encoded format, for description field it displays special character properly. 
I cannot edit content as they are coming from other source.

I'm not able to find the solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to output the title using [check_plain()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/check_plain/7). That would fix the problem.

Create a new views template for the title field, then use the following code:

```
print check_plain($output);
```

Comment: Have you flushed the cache after adding the new template?

Comment: Could u provide me with a screenshot for the output?